# User Uploads in DotNetNuke

Tags: dotnetnuke, user-input

1. As far as I know there's nothing special in DNN Core to limit the volume each user can upload files. Are there any ways like changing the code or installing any modules to handle that? (for example I don't want to let users to upload more than 100MB into a space allocated to them)
2. Is there any configuration in DNN core that puts user uploaded files in separate folders so that the browsing of files becomes easier? Any modules recommended. (for example I want to upload user12 files to a folder named user12 or anything similar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The setting to establish and enforce a quota for file storage would be set at the module level -- not the DNN/Portal level. It depends on the module that you use.
2. There does not appear to be too many choices regarding a DNN Module that would allow your users to upload various files into their own folder. However, I did find one that has two positive reviews that, if it works as promised, should suit your requirements

http://www.snowcovered.com/snowcovered2/Default.aspx?tabid=242&PackageID=16691

According to the author, it allows you to give users their own directory which they can upload to.

Answer (score 0):

DNN supports disk quotas on a per portal basis.  I am not aware of a module that allows disk quotas on a per user basis.

You can find the settings under Admin | Site Settings | Advanced Settings | Host Settings